# 18.04 Screen blanks after several hours, machine still running, all I get is a cursor

Tags: 18.04, lock

I can hear sound when I click around. Mouse is visible. When hitting the NumLock key it turns on and off so the computer is not locked up. I have to reboot the machine to get back in. I have spent a few hours getting the install just the way I like it so I would rather not reinstall.

Any ideas or guidance would help.  Newish user.

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that dbus-pm is not compatible to nvidia proprietary driver

try the following

```
sudo nano /etc/default/acpi-support
```

modify the line as follow

```
#SUSPEND_METHODS="dbus-pm dbus-hal pm-utils"
SUSPEND_METHODS="dbus-hal pm-utils"
```

then
    sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart

Comment: Just edited the file, well see what happens, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might also be related to your swap drive partition size. Make sure that you have at least 1.5x the size of your RAM memory allocated for the swap drive, 2x is recommended.

I faced the same situation weeks ago when i installed Kubuntu 18.04 with only one partition for it. I'm running a machine with 64gb RAM, NVidia 1080ti card, nvidia driver version 390 installed and the machine simply stopped when the lock screen showed up. The screen was black and the only thing i could do was to move the cursor around.

The only thing that fixed it for me was to re-install Linux with a good'ol swap partition of 1.5x the size of my RAM and now the machine is freakin' fast.

Even though the newer versions of Linux utilizes a swap file instead a swap partition, it is a good thing to allocate space for a swap partition. Personal opinion though. Good luck!